# code execution cannot complete as python38.dll not found

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have no idea what i have done to cause this but when running C:>python .... (image 1) i get this error (image two)
i've tried repairing the install and running a full scan for any viruses and it's all going normal but then i still get this error

image 1:

[image: console window]
image 2:

[image: error message]

i'd just like to thank anyone who may be able to help in advance too!

Answer (score 0):

When you type `py` command Python 3.9.2 is launched. However, when you type `python` the error message shows that `python38.dll` wasn't found which is a different version. It seems like you had different versions of Python and maybe some uninstallation process went wrong.

Are you able to check what do you have on PATH? The issue might be there. You can also try to uninstall all Python-related apps and install a fresh Python 3.9

Comment: so i've gone to uninstall all python apps and when i search python from the windows start section i have a "python" then subtext of run command, from there when i open the file location it takes me to a python application in the system32 folder which just so happens to be 3.8.3, everything related to python is gone other than installers and this python is sys32

could this be the issue?
if i was to delete this and reinstall everything again could this work?

Comment: What does the system environment variable Path look like?

Comment: i've managed to get it all back to normal, thank you though and thank you trivvz

Comment: Bling what was your solution? I am having the same issue as you described above.